# DataStax Enterprise Amazon AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, datastax-enterprise, datastax, amazon-ami

I'm trying to launch a new instance of DataStax AMI on a EC2 Amazon instance. I tried this in 2 different regions (us-east and eu-west), using these AMIs: ami-ada2b6c4, ami-814ec2e8 (us-east) and ami-7f33cd08, ami-b2212dc6 (eu-west)

I followed this documentation:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMI.html

So this is what I've done so far:

1. I've created a new security group (with those specific ports - I cannot upload the print screen because I have just created this account)
2. I've create a new key pair
3. I've launched the DataStax AMI with these configuration details:
   --clustername cluster --totalnodes 4 --version enterprise --username my_name
   --password my_password --searchnodes 2
   (I have verified my credentials - I can login here http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ )
4. After selecting the previous created security group & key pair I launched the instance.
5. I've connected to my DataStax Enterprise EC2 instance and this is the displayed log:

   Cluster started with these options:
   --clustername cluster --totalnodes 4 --version enterprise --username my_name
   --password **** --searchnodes 2

   03/12/15-08:59:23 Reflector: Received 1 of 2 responses from: [u'172.31.34.171']...
   Exception seen in ds1_launcher.py. Please check ~/datastax_ami/ami.log for more info.
   Please visit ....

and the ami.log shows these messages:

```
[INFO] 03/12/15-08:59:23 Reflector: Received 1 of 2 responses from: [u'172.31.34.171']
[ERROR] EC2 is experiencing some issues and has not allocated all of the resources in under 10 minutes.
Aborting the clustering of this reservation. Please try again.
[ERROR] Exception seen in ds1_launcher.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds1_launcher.py", line 22, in initial_configurations
ds2_configure.run()
 File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 1135, in run
File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 57, in exit_path
AttributeError: EC2 is experiencing some issues and has not allocated all of the resources in under 10 minutes.
Aborting the clustering of this reservation. Please try again.
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be an issue with Amazon EC2 instances.

looks like there are no available instances of that type in that region at that AZ at that moment.

another thing you can try is just using the repos install just opscenter in a ec2 instance that you already have (or a new one), and try to create the new nodes/cluster through opscenter, it's pretty simple and will let you choose the AMI, secGroup and keyPair you already have.

Comment: I have tried to create new nodes using opscenter, but they don't start successfully. When I've used community version everything worked just fine. The enterprise version is the problem

Comment: What error gives you with the new nodes? Are you usin dse 4.6.1?